# Installing MySQL-python error

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to install a Python package, but every time I get an error. I looked for a solution on different webpages, but none of them solved my preoblem. I do not know if I am doing something wrong or maybe the problem is somewhere else

```
$ sudo pip install MySQL-python

Collecting MySQL-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-kmndmtdh/MySQL-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-kmndmtdh/MySQL-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-kmndmtdh/MySQL-python/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-kmndmtdh/MySQL-python/
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-kmndmtdh/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        from setup_posix import get_config
      File "/tmp/pip-install-kmndmtdh/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Error messages:

[image: error_1]

[image: error_2]

Comment: Please don't post screen shots of error messages. It is preferable to actually copy the text of the message, paste it into your question and format it properly. Thanks.

Comment: kevin one of the responders asked me for screenshots from the terminal, i'm sorry if is a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following steps which I have used to install the "mysql-python",

1. Install python 2.7

   ```
   (base) [test@localhost ~]$ conda install python=2.7
   ```
2. Create the second environment(if you wish directly create 2.7 as a base environment)

   ```
   (base) [test@localhost ~]$ conda create -n test_mysql python=2.7
   ```
3. Activate the recent created environment which is installed with python2.7

   ```
   (base) [test@localhost ~]$ conda activate test_mysql
   ```
4. Install **mysql-python** in that environment

   ```
   (test_mysql) [test@localhost ~]$ conda install -c anaconda mysql-python
   ```
5. Check the installed packages

   ```
   (test_mysql) [test@localhost ~]$ conda list |grep -i mysql

   mysql-connector-c         6.1.11               h597af5e_1    anaconda

   mysql-python              1.2.5            py27h7b6447c_0    anaconda
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I made it